# Visual Studio 2008 DEBUG build of 32-bit appli CRASHES on a 64-bit Win 10 PC but same appli works when we install Visual Studio 2008 on 64-bit Win10

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm facing the following issue:

## **Background**

I have a Win32 legacy application (exe & dll's) and drivers (dll's) written on **Visual Studio 6.0** that used to run 
well in **Debug version** on Windows Xp (Please Note: We need it in DEBUG configuration & not Release). 
I copy the Visual studio 6.0's msvc* type dll's, MFC dll's & manifest files along with the exe to make it run.

## **Issue**:

The same legacy 32-bit application & driver dll's have now been **newly compiled in Visual Studio 2008 DEBUG** mode.
It is then copied to a PC running on **64-bit Windows 10** PC (also tried Windows 7 without success) **without having VS2008
installed**. I copy the VS2008's msvc* type dll's (*msvcp90d.dll, msvcr90d.dll*), MFC dll's and manifest file (*Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.manifest*) also along with the exe.

On launching this debug version of the application (it does many initialization activities on startup and also calls the init methods of driver dll's) it **crashes on starting up** both on a 64-bit Windows 10 & Windows 7 PC.

## **What works**:

When **VS2008 is installed** on the Windows 10 PC, the application's debug version **launches correctly** without crash and works fine.
(Also please note that same application's Debug build using the old Visual Studio 6.0 works fine on Windows 10).

## **What DOESN'T work**:

When VS2008 is NOT installed on a Windows 10 PC, the application's debug version crashes while it is being launched.

## **Requirement**

We absolutely need the **DEBUG** configuration of the application to run on the Windows 10 PC.

## **Development environment**

- OS for development: 64-bit Windows 7
- Target OS: 64-bit Windows 10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2008 SP1
- Application & driver dlls/exe's: 32-bit

I have tried many workarounds like building by using 32-bit paths in VS2008 ($\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows..), 
installed redistributables of VS2008 (both x86 & x64), 
running as 'Administrator' user,
running in compatibility mode (Win Xp..), 
copying dll's from system32 folder of a PC having VS2008 installed to a PC without VS2008 etc.. but the Debug build always crashes on it's startup.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.
Please let me know if you would like to have further details.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx

Comment: Crashes how? What error messages are generated?

Comment: Hi Hans Prassant,
Thanks for the link. It seems to be for VS2015. I couldnt find the same page for
VS2008.
I'd already tried some of the points listed in it (liek using DLL's from path \VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\). I'll try the others as well.

Comment: Hi Tim Randall,
Thanks for the response.
Just to precise: In fact, I've my application and also driver dll's which are both compiled in VS2008 now.
My application calls the init methods of the driver dll's and it crashes with the "Debug Assertion failed!" error dialog box.

Comment: What do the event logs say? What's the rest of the message along with *Debug Assertion Failed*?

Comment: install debug runtimes from **C:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86** on the new PCs

Comment: A failed debug assertion dialog popping up is not a crash. It's an indication for a bug in your code. Fix the bug. The assertion dialog has options to identify the issue. As an unrelated note: The debug versions of the runtime library are not redistributable. Make sure your legal team is informed that you plan to violate Visual Studio's EULA.